# Auto calculate values onkeyup with JS/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help with auto counting (without refresh) javascript/jquery function which let me count me by the formula:

Chance = Sum (input by person) * Number.

The problem is, that is a lot of fields, about ~100, but i need to calculate the "Chance" for every  separately.
Here is the code, for question to be understood:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Chance</th>
    <th>Sum</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="id1" /></td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>0.5</td>
    <td><span id="chance1" >NEED AUTO VALUE AFTER COUNTING HERE!</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" onkeyup="some function?" name="sum1" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="id2" /></td>
    <td>test2</td>
    <td>0.7</td>
    <td><span id="chance2" >NEED AUTO VALUE AFTER COUNTING HERE!</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" onkeyup="some function?" name="sum2" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="id3" /></td>
    <td>test3</td>
    <td>0.9</td>
    <td><span id="chance3" >NEED AUTO VALUE AFTER COUNTING HERE!</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" onkeyup="some function?" name="sum3" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5xch9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `parents` method to find the relevant `tr` row for the `sum` input in question, and then find the number and chance cells inside that row.

```
$('input[name^=sum]').on("keyup", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $parent = $this.parents('tr');
    var $chance = $parent.find('.chance');
    var $number = $parent.find('.number');    
    $chance.text($number.text() * $this.val());
});
```

(caching the different nodes(td/span tags) isn't necessary, I wrote it like this to improve readability)

You can modify the markup to something like:

```
<tr>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td class="number">0.5</td>
    <td><span class="chance" id="chance1" >NEED AUTO VALUE AFTER COUNTING HERE!</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="sum1" /></td>
</tr>
```

(adding `.number` and `.chance` classes makes it easier to find the desired nodes inside the row)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/5xch9/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do something like this (just add a selector for the inputs):

```
function keyUpHandler(e){
  //whatever you want to do with the keyUp
  //e.target will contain the element
}
$('.inputKeyUp').on('keyup',keyUpHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5xch9/4/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
     //handler to trigger sum event
     $(".txt").each(function () {

         $(this).keyup(function () {
             calculateSum();
         });
     });

 });

 function calculateSum() {

     var sum = 0;
     //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
     $(".txt").each(function () {

         //add only if the value is number
         if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
             sum += parseFloat(this.value);
         }

     });
     //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
     $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
 }
```

Comment: somehow its not working. i've added onkeyup="calculateSum()", added txt class to input elements, but its not working :|

Comment: @EimantasGabrielius:No need to add onkeyup event to each textbox.jquery will handle this.Add jquery reference in in your page

Comment: yes it's working now, but how should i make it for more than 1 tr ?
i try:
$("#sum1").html(sum.toFixed(2));
$("#sum2").html(sum.toFixed(2));
$("#sum3").html(sum.toFixed(2));
but not working

I need to make every row calculate seperately/individualy

Comment: @geek Couldn't you simply use `$('.txt').keyup(calculateSum);`?

Comment: so is there anyway to make that code working for each row individually ?

Comment: @EimantasGabrielius I think I know what you mean, see my answer